# not able to format the jboss logs into json send it to the rsyslog

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am using JBOSS 6.4 EAP version.

Jboss log manager sends the log messages to Rsyslog in json format. Rsyslog is accepting the logs in json format as mentioned below.
Somehow I am not getting how to format the jboss log message to json and send the same to Rsyslog.

JBOSS SERVER log manager(need to generate the logs in JSON format as below)     ->Rsyslog

```
sample JSON format:
------------------

{"logfile": "ABC.log", "srcfile":"A.java", "lineno":129, "log":"This is an info message"}
```

I am using the below configuration under standalone.xml under logging subsystem section.

```
<syslog-handler name="SYSLOG">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <server-address value="localhost"/>
    <port value="514"/>
    <facility value="local-use-4"/>
</syslog-handler>
```

Can somebody help how to format the jboss log message to json and send the same to rsyslog?

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: Are you wanting the message only formatted with JSON?

Comment: yes James, I need message format in JSON

Comment: can anybody help how to add logging pattern in the above mentioned syslog handler